# Cassandra12 error - Can't open incompatible SSTable! Current version ic

Tags: cassandra

After installing cassandra12 with homebrew, it quits with the following message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't open incompatible SSTable! Current version ic, found file: /usr/local/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_keyspaces/system-schema_keyspaces-jb-9

Computer-computer:desktop $ java -version  
java version "1.7.0_45"  
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)  
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

Installed version is `cassandra 1.2.11`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because you had an older version of cassandra running before. Either remove the directories cassandra uses for logs, data and caching (in your case `/usr/local/var/lib/cassandra/` or change the data / cache / log directory in cassandra.yaml.

Just for clarity's sake, you'll loose whatever data is in those directories.

Comment: Thanks, now I'm getting the following:  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown commitlog version 3

Comment: You haven't removed the directory where the commitlog lives. Sorry the above should be `/usr/local/var/lib/cassandra/` This will get rid of the commit_log directory, the data directory and the saved_caches directory which need to be empty before a new cassandra version is started up.

Comment: The directory could also be named `/var/lib/cassandra` and you wight have to re-create the directory structure if you just delete the directory. Better make a backup and delete directory contents instead.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem downgrading my cassandra version from `2.0.6` to `1.2.12`,

#### which I fixed by removing the content of /var/lib/cassandra/,

```
mv /var/lib/cassandra/{commitlog,data,saved_caches} ~/Desktop/cassandra_backup
```

Or removing completely

```
rm -r /var/lib/cassandra/{commitlog,data,saved_caches}
```